# firebird: how to use '%' in where clause?

Tags: php, firebird, where-clause

dear all.  i'm familiar with MySQL but not in Firebird.

i try to search some particular data inside DB.But after i try to use '%' in where cluse i get some error message:

```
Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 3, column 43 %
```

this my script:

```
$ssWhere .= " PROD_DATE LIKE ''%".$_POST['sSearch_8']."%'' ";
```

whether i cant use '%' in where clause in firebird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to specify single quote once:

```
$ssWhere .= " PROD_DATE LIKE '%".$_POST['sSearch_8']."%' ";
```

Comment: great..at 1st time i'm use one single quotes.but after that someone tell me to use two single quotes to prevent SQL injection. may be not all that must use two single quotes.;)

Comment: @klox: There are different ways to prevent sql injection not the one suggested by your friend. You can search on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

SELECT a.*
FROM tablea a
WHERE a.fieldname LIKE 'A%'

Comment: thanks for your advise. but i have found the answer like Sarfraz answer.